Mellin-Barnes representation of the ratio of first kind Bessel functions
I have a question regarding the Mellin-Barnes representation of Bessel functions of the first kind. I know that the product of these functions admits the following integral representation
$J_{\mu}(x)J_{\nu}(x) = \int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \frac{ds}{2\pi\,i}\,\frac{\Gamma(-s)\,\Gamma(2s+\mu+\nu+1)}{\Gamma(s+\mu+1)\,\Gamma(s+\nu+1)\,\Gamma(s+\mu+\nu+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2s+\mu+\nu}\, \ ,$
where the path of integration separates the poles of $\Gamma(-s)$ to those of $\Gamma(2s+\mu+\nu+1)$. I was wondering if there is an analogous relation for the ratio as well. That is to say, is it possible to provide a Mellin-Barnes integral representation of the ratio $J_{\mu}(x)/J_{\nu}(x)$, or are there some mathematical obstructions (that I'm not able to see) that would prevent such a possibility?
Many thanks in advance

When the index $\nu$ is real, the function $J_{\nu}(z)$ has an infinite number of real zeros which correspond to an infinite number of real poles in $\frac{1}{J_{\nu}(z)}$.
